# Android: PlaybackOverlayFragment not working

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I am working on an Android TV app and when I have started working on the project code it throws an error for PlaybackOverlayFragment, stating it cannot resolve symbol PlaybackOverlayFragment

```
public class PlaybackOverlayFragment extends android.support.v17.leanback.app.PlaybackOverlayFragment
```

currently in my gradle file it reads :

```
compile 'com.android.support:leanback-v17:27.1.1'
```

The original project was in compile sdk version 26 and I upgraded it to 27, is this throwing error because of it?

Answer (score 5):

`PlaybackOverlayFragment` was deprecated some time ago and then completely removed in v27.
You should move away from deprecated API as soon as possible because they may be removed any time in the future.
The doc says you shoud use `PlaybackFragment` instead which was also deprecated in 27.1.0... So now you should use `PlaybackSupportFragment`
Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/PlaybackFragment